# O que são essas mensagems de erro que aparecem na Logcat?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arquivo, áudio

Olá, estou tendo essas mensagens abaixo, na minha Logcat de uma MainActivity do Android Studio. Como interpretá-las e resolvê-las?

```
01-16 11:27:34.088 15846-15846/? W/Glide: Load failed for /storage/emulated/0/9fe457b5-7baf-459d-be34-76ec5c2bcf74audio_record.3gp with size [80x80] 
class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
 Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{FileInputStream->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
  Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->GifDrawable->Drawable}
   Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->Bitmap->Drawable}
   Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
 Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{ParcelFileDescriptor->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
   Cause (1 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ParcelFileDescriptor->Bitmap->Drawable}
   Cause (2 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ParcelFileDescriptor->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
 Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{AssetFileDescriptor->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
   Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{AssetFileDescriptor->Bitmap->Drawable}
```

Podem me ajudar?

Obrigada!

Comment: Fazer a mesma pergunta repetidamente não fará com que ela seja respondida. Deve editar a primeira e adicionar novos detalhes.

Comment: @ramaral Tá bem! Obrigada pela dica!